# Is it possible to configure a supermicro X7DBU based system, with ESB2, to see HDDs greater than 750GB?

Tags: raid, supermicro

I'm currently running a Supermicro 1U server, with a X7DBU motherboard. When I boot up into RAID utility, I can either use ESB2, or Adaptec. Either way, The 3TB HDD (SATA) I put into it, is read as a 750GB drive. The server runs ESXi 5.5, and it sees (instead of 3TB) a 2TB, and 1TB in place. I can effectively still use the HDD, but my intention is to use 3x 3TB SATA drives for a RAID 5 storage.

Is there any way for me to update the system so that it will see the full 3TB?

Comment: I can't answer your question as it is. But I can offer an alternative in case you don't find an answer: install a third-party RAID card. This is what I do on my supermicro 1u servers and workstations.

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to a SuperMicro tech who said you need a 3rd party raid card. I know this because I have the exact same board, with the same problem.